# May I use CDN for whole website (PHP, Apache, MySQL) or just for images and CSS, JS files?

Tags: hosting, cdn, cloud-hosting, dedicated-server, uptime

May I use CDN for whole website (PHP, Apache, MySQL) or just for images and CSS, JS files?

What's the best choice > cloud-hosting or dedicated-hosting? Does CDN has that support?

Witch hosting you suggest me the best - the fastest, stablest 100% uptime, CDN, not expensive at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got three questions in one here, so let's take them in the order you asked:

1. Typically, you would use a CDN for serving static assets such as Images/CSS/JS.
2. CDN and Cloud/Static are not the same thing. With CDN, you provide the CDN your assets and they take care of the rest. Cloud/Static are used for dynamic content and you would configure things yourself.
3. It all depends on your requirements and application. There's really no such thing as 100% uptime, it just won't happen. You can, however, come very close. I would recommend Amazon, their Cloudfront offering is downright cheap and their new Free Tier for EC2 (cloud servers) is hard to pass up...

Comment: Thanks for your post! Could you suggest me to use http://www.rackspace.com or http://mediatemple.net hosting services?

Comment: I would go with Rackspace. I've had a **very** positive experience with them. Oh, and if my response answered your question, please do me a favor and click the checkmark next to my original response. Thanks!